# Java - constructor apparently missing, operators overloaded

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, package

I've declared a new "world" object in another class like so:

```
fray.World world = new fray.World();
```

the java compiler is complaining it can't find the constructor (it's fine with the position of the class in the `fray` package).

I have the following constructors in the fray.World class:

```
    World() {
        this(100, 100, 100);
    }

    World(int width) {
        this(width, 100, 100);
    }

    World(int width, int length) {
        this(width, length, 100);
    }

    World(int width, int length, int height) {
        this.x = new int[width];
        this.y = new int[length];
        this.z = new int[height];

        this.entities = new Entity[0];
    }
```

what's going on?

Comment: from where are you trying to instantiate the class? Same package `fray` or from a different package?

Comment: A currently unpackaged class.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the *visibility* of your constructors so that you can use them in other packages, they currently have package level access. You can try making them `public`.

Comment: I thought for a moment that would fix it, but unfortunately the error is still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `World` is a `static inner class`, you will need to use:

```
fray.World world = new fray().new World();
```

Comment: fray's a package, not a class- so the compiler just complains it can't find the fray class.

Comment: the spelling's bang on and the full class might be a bit big-
this is World.java
http://pastebin.com/NuskJeps

Comment: I compiled this class with Èclipse & with `javac` from an unpackaged class and got no compile errors.

Comment: That class compiles fine. The error arises when I try to construct that class in the class I'm currently working on debugging - bear with me, I'm something of a newbie programmer and most of this was written during times I decided to stay up all night to avoid sleeping in through lectures: 
http://pastebin.com/XnJBR4aU

Comment: Sry, could not replicate this error even with all the code. No problem finding constructor.

Comment: huh... strange. Welp, I have no idea why this is doing that then! Thanks for trying though.